# How do I destroy ibatis connection pool?

Tags: java, database, connection-pooling, ibatis

I am using ibatis 2.3.4.726. implementing use case where I need to create and destroy DB connection pool in a loop, as a part of some DB diagnostic experiment. could not find any API that destroys a DB connection pool. Appreciate any pointers. Thanks

Comment: I think if you are use "<dataSource type="POOLED">" , then you don't need to close the connection & it will handle by Hibernate.

Comment: I understand closing connection (returning to pool) is handled already. Here I need to destroy the DB connection pool (no connections to DB in netstat), not just close a connection. Hope I clarified my question.

Comment: is this spring project ? try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532302/how-to-shutdown-connection-pool-on-context-unload?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: For spring app this would have been a solution, but no mine is non-spring app.